# How to turn the desktop into symbolic link. [UBUNTU]

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, symbolic-link

Running Ubuntu 18.04 and want to siphon my desktop files to my other drive with the use of symbolic links, but the command:

```
sudo ln -s media/ragnvaldr/Desktop home/ragnvaldr
```

won't work because home/ragnvaldr/Desktop already exists. Are there any ways to get around this? I.E. make a already existing directory into a symlink? Or possibly deleting the desktop temporarily, then running the command without screwing anything up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply name the link something else, e.g. `sudo ln -s /media/ragnvaldr/Desktop /home/ragnvaldr/new-directory`. If it's important that the link is called Desktop, then yes you do need to get whatever files you want to keep out of harms way out of Desktop and then delete the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to not be in a GUI session - the "desktop" view is browsing a folder, and so it would be kinda bad if it were deleted while you have a desktop session going.

Check my answer on this super-similar question for details - [Ubuntu 18.04: Issue changing the default directories](https://superuser.com/questions/1468961/ubuntu-18-04-issue-changing-the-default-directories/1468968)

In short, get to a console only VT *after* you've logged out of your desktop session.  At that point, you can rename/move your current ~/Desktop and replace it with a symlink.  I prefer to go to the destination directory (`/home/username`) and link it in with `ln /path/to/real/location/Desktop .`

Comment: That is my other question I asked... Hence the similarity. I just didn't think it would work with in the case of the desktop. Honestly, your answer helped my so far, but it was a little advanced. I was hoping someone would xplain this specific case in laymans terms.

Comment: But i was just being an idiot anyway, because I didn't think about just renaming my desktop.